# How to check if an annotation is a ClassVar in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following code:

```py
from typing import ClassVar

class A:
    a: ClassVar[str]
```

How do I check, at runtime, if `a` has been declared as a `ClassVar`?

I tried using `isinstance` and `issubclass` but they don't seem to work:

```py
>>> A.__annotations__
{'a': typing.ClassVar[str]}
>>> x = A.__annotations__["a"]
>>> isinstance(x, typing.ClassVar)
TypeError: typing.ClassVar cannot be used with isinstance()
>>> issubclass(x, typing.ClassVar)
TypeError: typing.ClassVar cannot be used with issubclass()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this (apparently) by using `__origin__`:

```py
>>> x = A.__annotations__["a"]
>>> x.__origin__ is ClassVar
True
```

Comment: Starting in Python 3.8, one can use `typing.get_origin(annotation) is ClassVar`.